# Concat CString with variable number of arguments

Tags: c++11

I want con-cat CString with below code :

```
CString ConcateString(CString cstr, ...)
{
   CString cstringFinal;
   va_list argList;
   va_start(argList, cstr);
   CString str = cstr;
while (str != argList)
{
    cstringFinal += va_arg(argList, CString);
}
   va_end(argList);
   return cstringFinal;
}
```

but it not work.

I try test this with ConcateString(L"ja", L"ck", L"te", L"st"); bot I have exception.

can you help me for fix this?

Comment: What is `CString`? Is it [the MFC/ATL `CstringT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5bzxfsea.aspx) for `char`? Furthermore, what is the exception you get? Lastly, please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: By the way, using C++ classes and objects together with C varargs is really not something I would recommend. Since you tagged this with C++11 you should be able to use [*parameter packs*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack) which you should use instead.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude for CString see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa300688(v=vs.60).aspx

Comment: So you're using old Visual Studio 6? Then you should probably mention it in the body, as well as using the `c++` tag instead (since VS6 is far from capable of C++11). And we still need to know the "exception" as well as see a MCVE.

Comment: I use VS 2015 .....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was kind of hidden since the call wasn't formatted properly as code, but the problem *is* with the mix of C++ objects and you use of vararg functions.

When you do

```
ConcateString(L"ja", L"ck", L"te", L"st")
```

the compiler will ***not*** convert the strings to `CString` objects. Instead what you have is a "list" of `wchar_t*`. You need to fetch the pointers as pointers, not as `CString` objects:

```
cstringFinal += va_arg(argList, wchar_t*);
```

---

Since you use VS2015 it should be able to handle [template parameter packs](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack), which means you can do something like

```
CString ConcateString(CString const& first)
{
    return first;
}

template<typename ...T>
CString ConcateString(CString const& first, T... arguments)
{
    return first + ConcateString(arguments...);
}
```

Comment: yahhhh, tank you, what is your idea about while condition, it not correct

Comment: @mail Oh that's incorrect as well. There's no specified end to a varargs list. You need some way to explicitly end it that can be detected (like passing a null pointer?). Or use *parameter packs* (as I mentioned before, and now added an example of).